# Importing RSA Public and Private Keys to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, key, rsa

I'm a bit new to RSA Encryption. I made an RSA Key Pair using PGPfreeware 6.5.8, and I'm writing a VB.NET code that will encrypt and decrypt a field in an XML file. I made an export to the RSA key that includes both Public and Private Keys and I got the file in .asc extension (For ASCII). and I got the public and private keys in this format:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGPfreeware 6.5.8 for non-commercial use <http://www.pgp.com>
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=pxF6
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGPfreeware 6.5.8 for non-commercial use <http://www.pgp.com>
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=ds/P
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

When I tried to pass the public and private keys to my RSACryptoServiceProvider object, I found out that these keys are in a form that is not available for .NET to deal with them; .NET deals with XML Public and Private Keys only. I searched through the internet and found out that the keys in this format are a result of converting the original text using Base64, so I tried converting them back to normal texts instead of Base64 texts so I can -hopefully- import them to my object, but I got a FormatException saying: invalid char in a Base-64 string. What am I doing wrong? and how exactly can I make my files work as the Public and Private Keys for my RSA object?

Thank you.

Comment: The format incompatibility goes way beyond the base64 (actually ascii armor) encoding; OpenPGP key formats are fundamentally incompatible with any format supported by .Net.  There *is* a third-party library written in C# called Bouncycastle that can help, but obviously that isn't VB.

Comment: I saw that library (BouncyCastle) and some other libraries while I was searching through the internet, but I'm still looking if there is a way of either covert the files' format to a readable XML format (which is not according to your reply now), or use a new third party app that is compatible with VB.NET for RSA Keys' Generation. Thanks for your reply.